# Как "отвязать" пользователя от приложения Facebook?

Tags: yii2, facebook

Подскажите, пожалуйста, использую для входа на сайт [Yii2 authclient](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient)

Как с помощью данного модуля или без него удалить(убрать разрешения пользователя с приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете снять пользователя с клиента с помощью экшина

```
public function actionRemoveAuth($client) {
    Auth::find()->where('user_id = :user_id AND source = :client', [
        ':user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id, 
        ':client' => $client->getId()
    ])->one()->delete();
}
```

Если под разрешениями понимается набор scope для конкретного клиента, то этот набор можно передать в config-е

```
'authClientCollection' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
    'clients' => [
        'facebook' => [
            'authUrl'      => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
            'class'        => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
            'clientId'     => '*****',
            'clientSecret' => '*****',
            'scope'        => [
                'email', 
                'public_profile', 
                'user_about_me', 
                'user_location', 
                'user_work_history',
            ]
        ],
    ], ],
```